# Dynamic jQuery/MySQL dropdown menu

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu, dynamic-data

I'm trying to create a PHP booking system, where customers can go into the system, select a date/time from available slots in a calendar-like interface.

I need to figure out a way to use jQuery or some other convention to pull the available time slots and put them into a drop-down menu so the user can select one and book it. The time slot selected would then go into the MySQL database as being booked. Any clues as to where I could get information on doing this? Any ideas from anyone who has done something similar?

Comment: appointment booking is one of the more complex projects to tackle if you arent very experienced. theres a whole lot of information you need to figure out first, how are you determining what times are available or already booked, can more than one appointment be on the same time slot, etc.

Comment: that being said, stackoverflow is a show code and get it fixed, questions like this dont belong here if you arent even started yet!

Comment: This is a very broad question and is unlikely to get answered. You'll have more luck if you start to implement your project and ask specific and concrete questions along the way. You might want to read through these sections of the Help to know what is likely to be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I know that I don't have code samples, and I have started on the project, I'm just not really sure where to begin with this particular section, I just need to be pointed in the right direction. I'm not looking for a specific code solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need an `Ajax` request.

`Ajax` stands for Asynchronous Javascript and XML, but it can convert the response of the page to a JSON as well.

There are some libraries in Javascript that ease the use of this technique, like jQuery.

You could pull the data from an php page asynchronously (i.e., without blocking the page) and display it for the user. You can find many exemples like these among the internet.

The jQuery documentation on Ajax is here: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: Does this mean you can pull data from the MySQL database with PHP, and then get that data with jQuery Ajax and display it to the user without a page reload?

Comment: Yes, jQuery makes that relatively easy.